# Multiple framebuffers and textures not working on intel drivers

Tags: opengl, intel, framebuffer

I'm writing an application using PyOpengl and PySide. My main machine is installed with ubuntu and an nvidia card (proprietary drivers), the premise is just to tell that the application is working properly in this setting.

I'm testing this application on a machine with an intel hd 3000 and Ubuntu 12.10, the drivers are the default intel drivers. Everything is working so far except for the application of multiple post-processing filters.

The process works like that:

render the scene and output a color texture (texture0) using a framebuffer object (called fb0).

render the first postprocessing effect by binding the textures produced in the previous step. The processed color output is saved in another texture (extratexture1) by using another framebuffer (fb1).

render another postprocessing effect by using the new color texture (extratexture2 and fb2).

render the result on the screen.

What I obtain is a white screen (my background color perhaps).

If I remove the last step and render the extratexture1, I obtain the correct result. If I remove the second step only and render the extratexture2 I obtain the correct result. Therefore the problem should not be in the texture initialization code.

It's like that this driver doesn't support more than 2 framebuffers (+ default one) at a time. Or probably failing to reset some important state.

Was anybody able to code a similar thing on an intel video card? I'm running out of ideas of what the problem can be.

I add some example code to troubleshoot any error:

Initialization of framebuffers and textures, at initialization time. The texture are regenerated at each resize.

```
   self.fb0, self.fb2, self.fb1 = glGenFramebuffers(3)
   # Creation of texture0

   glDrawBuffers(1, np.array([GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0], dtype='uint32'))

   # Creation of extratexture1
   # Creation of extratexture2
```

Creation of each texture:

```
def create_color_texture(fb, width, height):
    # Simple wrapper for glGenTexture and glTexImage2D
    texture = Texture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, width, height, GL_RGB, GL_RGB,
                      GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE)

    # Set some parameters
    texture.set_parameter(GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST)
    texture.set_parameter(GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR)        

    glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, fb)
    glViewport(0, 0, width, height)
    glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_TEXTURE_2D,
                           texture.id, 0)
    return texture
```

Code that draws the texture to screen:

```
def render(self, fb, textures):
    # We need to render to a quad
    glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, fb)
    glViewport(0, 0, self.widget.width(), self.widget.height())
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT)

    glUseProgram(self.quad_program)

    qd_id = glGetUniformLocation(self.quad_program, "rendered_texture")
    # Setting up the texture
    glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0)
    textures['color'].bind()
    # Set our "rendered_texture" sampler to user Texture Unit 0
    glUniform1i(qd_id, 0)

    # Set resolution
    glUniform2f(glGetUniformLocation(self.quad_program, 'resolution'), self.widget.width(), self.widget.height())
    # Set gamma value
    glUniform1f(glGetUniformLocation(self.quad_program, 'gamma'), self.gamma)

    # Let's render a quad
    quad_data = np.array([-1.0, -1.0, 0.0,
                          1.0, -1.0, 0.0,
                          -1.0,  1.0, 0.0,
                          -1.0,  1.0, 0.0,
                          1.0, -1.0, 0.0,
                          1.0,  1.0, 0.0],
                         dtype='float32')

    vboquad = vbo.VBO(quad_data)
    vboquad.bind()

    glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, 0, None)        
    glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY)

    # draw "count" points from the VBO
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 6)

    vboquad.unbind()
    glDisableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY)
```

Comment: Just a few pointers generally about debugging such problems:
Nvidia drivers are known to be very permissive, they just fix your errors. Perhaps try on an AMD machine if you can to see if it makes a difference( AMD strictly follows the standards ).
As a debug measure, check for OpenGL errors. If your program isnt platform-dependent you could try it on another platform to see if the drivers are causing the problem. You could also try to use GDebugger( AMD software but should work with all cards ), tough I am not sure if its available for linux based platforms.

Comment: @akaltar thank you very much for your suggestion. I tested on the intel card on windows and the thing is working. This is a pretty sad situation, I should do more testing though (like on more linux driver versions), especially on the ATI cards, so I can exclude a bug in my code.